# V8: create new variable scope

Tags: javascript, v8

In JavaScript, when I enter a new function, I get a new local variable scope. E.g. like this:

```
function f() {
     var x = 42; // this is in our local variable scope
     // other code
}
```

I want to do the same now in V8. I have `other code` as a `String` and compile it via `Script::Compile` and run it via `Script::Run`.

Right now, I create a new `Context` but I think this is total overkill. It also means that I have to reinit my globals in the new context.

Comment: To answer this, it would be helpful to know what effect you are trying to achieve or avoid. If you DO have a local variable scope, what important thing now works in your code?

Comment: @BradWerth: The variables are visible only to `Script`. And it must be *very* cheap to create this variable scope, esp. because I might end up to call that recursively.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get your C++ side script to run in a new isolated context, I assume because you don't want it accidentally aliasing or modifying the global environment. In that case, before you execute your code, do this:

```
std::string sScopedCode = "(function(){" + sYourCode + "})();"
```

That will ensure the code in sYourCode is kept isolated from other invocations you might make.

Comment: I want the variables to be constructed in C++ because I need to access them there, too.

Comment: I've never discovered a V8 way to mimic "var" behavior. May I suggest you add the variables as properties of the function? That is close to the behavior you are seeking, though you will have to be careful with any "this" usage in the rest of your code.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a possibility / workaround. In the internal V8 namespace and its internal code, I have seen such local scope variables but I don't like to use the internal API.